# Adobe phonegap build service and facebook plugin

Tags: facebook, cordova, adobe

I'm having an issue with adobe phonegap build service and facebook plugin on Android.
here is my config.xml file:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="123myappid123" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="Flyclub" />
</gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
```

i've created a keystore,

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore fly.keystore -alias fly -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

extracted his hashkey,

```
keytool -exportcert -alias fly -keystore ~/Desktop/Flyclub/fly.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

in my facebook developer i set the setting like that:
[image]

MY KEY HASH i replaced with the keyhash i extracted.
Notes: its working well with iphone. also is working well without an facebook app on the android, i mean with a popup window.

after i signed the application on adobe phonegap build service, i installed it on my Android phone which has facebook app installed.

after i click the red button it's opening facebook login dialog.
[image]

it opens facebook dialog, with facebook header but with a blank screen
[image]

is there anything im doing wrong?!

thank you all!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you solve it:
just go to the facebook developer portal, go into your app, then Status & Review, and turn on the app to live.

thats it.